# How do I solve the following harp errors on my project?

Tags: node.js, harp

Please, I ran "harp version" command to get the Harp version on my system, but it prompted the following error on my PowerShell.

PS C:> harp version

```
harp : C:\Users\GACHIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\node_modules\node-
sass\lib\binding.js:15
```

At line:1 char:1

harp version

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\GACHIO...b\binding.js:15 
 :String) [], RemoteException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
    ^
Error: Missing binding C:\Users\GACHIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\no
de_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows
64-bit with Node.js 10.x
```

Found bindings for the following environments:

```
Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running npm install.
Run npm rebuild node-sass to download the binding for your current
environment.
at module.exports (C:\Users\GACHIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\harp\no
de_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
at Object. (C:\Users\GACHIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\har
p\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\GACHIO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\har
p\node_modules\terraform\lib\stylesheet\processors\scss.js:1:74)
```